# Rename file/directory using JFileChooser() and JButton()

Tags: java, swing, file, nullpointerexception, jfilechooser

I'm trying to rename file or directory using JFileChooser() and JButton(). But it gives me a "**NullPointer exeption**" in line 81 where I have 
**action listener**

```
        // button action
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String newFileName = textField.getText();

                // exeption is here!!!
                File oldFile = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile(), null);

                File newFileOrDirectoryName = new File(newFileName);
                if (oldFile.renameTo(newFileOrDirectoryName)) {
                    System.out.println("renamed");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            }
        });
```

I have to select some file or directory from my **FileChooser()**, then write new name for file or directory in **TextField()** and then push the **Button()** to rename it.Can you say where I go wrong and how to solve this problem.

[image: Exeption occurs when I push the button]

This is a full code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class App {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JFileChooser fileChooser;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    App window = new App();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public App() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 539, 469);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 246, 143));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Rename file or package");
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        label.setBounds(10, 0, 302, 32);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("New file/package name");
        label_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        label_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        label_1.setBounds(10, 358, 194, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label_1);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(10, 387, 179, 32);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton button = new JButton("Rename");
        button.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        button.setBounds(199, 384, 151, 34);
        button.addActionListener(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);

        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setBounds(10, 51, 505, 289);
        frame.getContentPane().add(fileChooser);

        // button action
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String newFileName = textField.getText();
                File oldFile = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile(), null);
                File newFileOrDirectoryName = new File(newFileName);
                if (oldFile.renameTo(newFileOrDirectoryName)) {
                    System.out.println("renamed");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: [crossposted](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/493903/rename-filedirectory-using-jfilechooser-and-jbutton)

Comment: @mKorbel I hope that this is allowed

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're passing `null` to the File constructor at line 81, which give a NullPointerException when passed null. This can be read in the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

I think the solution is to remove the 'new File' part and replace it by:

```
File oldFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
```

The bug was actually quite easy to see by pasting the code into IntelliJ:

[image: IntelliJ screenshot]

Comment: Yes, my exeption's gone when I pass these parameters: **File oldFile = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile(), newFileName);** but **oldFile.renameTo(newFileOrDirectoryName)** returns false. And I don't know where I go wrong

Comment: According to your suggestions, the **if statement** gives **NullPointer**. Something's wrong with this: **oldFile.renameTo(newFileOrDirectoryName)**

Comment: No, it doesn't. The arrow points to the `null`, not to the if statement.